# SQL Server - difference between stopping and disabling Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, t-sql, amazon-rds

Can someone explain - didn't find it in MS's docs - what is the difference in behaviour of `EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job` and `EXEC dbo.sp_update_job @enabled = 0`? I'm preparing for AWS RDS reboot and need to turn off any job/ssis/dms that points to/from my RDS instance.

Goal is to stop any activity happening around RDS without brutal/forced connection break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stop a job, you stop the currently running agent job. If you disable a job that means that the job will not start at it's next scheduled time.

Take, for example, a job that starts every hour, on the hour, and takes 10 minutes to complete. At 13:05 you stop the job; the process currently running is terminated (likely triggering rollbacks for any open transactions). The job will then run again at 14:00.

For the same job, at 16:01 you disable it. I believe, (though it's not [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/disable-or-enable-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15) that I could see) the job will continue running to completion, however, at 17:00 it *will not* start, and nor will it at any later dates until it is enabled (again).